# Adding a '-' to my string in C#

Tags: c#

I Have  a string in the form "123456789".
While displaying it on the screen I want to show it as 123-456-789.
Please let me knwo how to add the "-" for every 3 numbers.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it is allways 9 digits or it can be unlimited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll go ahead and give the `Regex` based solution:

```
string rawNumber = "123456789";
var formattedNumber = Regex.Replace(rawNumber, @"(\d{3}(?!$))", "$1-");
```

That regex breaks down as follows:

```
(        // Group the whole pattern so we can get its value in the call to Regex.Replace()
  \d     // This is a digit
  {3}    // match the previous pattern 3 times
  (?!$)  // This weird looking thing means "match anywhere EXCEPT the end of the string"
)
```

The `"$1-"` replacement string means that whenever a match for the above pattern is found, replace it with the same thing (the $1 part), followed by a `-`. So in `"123456789"`, it would match `123` and `456`, but not `789` because it's at the end of the string. It then replaces them with `123-` and `456-`, giving the final result `123-456-789`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904308.aspx):

```
s = s.Substring(0, 3) + "-" + s.Substring(3, 3) + "-" + s.Substring(6, 3);
```

or a regular expression ([ideone](http://ideone.com/OohJO)):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\d{3}(?=\d)", "$0-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop also if the string length is not fixed to 9 digits as follows

```
string textnumber = "123456789"; // textnumber = "123456789012346" also it will work
            string finaltext = textnumber[0]+ "";
            for (int i = 1; i < textnumber.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
                {
                    finaltext = finaltext + textnumber[i] + "-";
                }
                else
                {
                    finaltext = finaltext + textnumber[i];
                }
            }
            finaltext = finaltext.Remove(finaltext.Length - 1);
```